# Numbers that were accidently mixed up

Tags: phrase-requests

Which word is a better use if 2 numbers were mixed up what do we say inverted or interchanged exp 256 instesad of 265

Comment: Digits were interchanged.  The number was scrambled.

Comment: *Transposed*...

Comment: Expanding on deadrat's comment:   www.businessdictionary.com/definition/transposition-error.html

Comment: Numeric anagrams ?

Comment: If the digits were changed intentionally, you could say that the digits were permuted; if they were changed by mistake, the answer given below is appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

It's called a [*transposition error*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcription_error#Transposition_error):

> As the name suggest, transposition errors occur when characters have
>   “transposed”—that is, they have switched places.

See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Check_digit#Design